# Centre images in a single row table

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to get three images on a single line, one left-justified, one centred and the last one right-justified. I've settled on using a single row table to do it, but am having a hard time getting the images to be centred within their respective cells.

Is there a better way of doing it than I've chosen? I'm not going to use the `<td align="center">` attribute as it's been deprecated in HTML5, so am looking for a way to do it using CSS. This is what I have at the moment (I've set the table border attribute to '1' so I can see how the image alignment within the cell renders):

```
<style>
  .centre_image
  {
  float:center;
  }
</style>

<body>
<table border="1">
    <tr>
    <td class="centre_image">
        <object type="image/svg+xml" data="images/lawfirms.svg">   
          <img src="images/lawfirms.png" alt=""/>     
        </object>
    </td>
    <td class="centre_image">
        <object type="image/svg+xml" data="images/industry.svg">     
          <img src="images/industry.png" alt=""/>     
        </object>
    </td>
    <td class="centre_image">
        <object type="image/svg+xml" data="images/in-house.svg">     
          <img src="images/in-house.png" alt=""/>     
        </object>
    </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This gives the following result in Firefox 19.0 on Ubuntu:
[image]

and the following result in Chrome 25.0: 
[image]

EDIT - here is the full HTML after making the changes referred to in j08691's answer:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>     
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">     
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8"/>     
<title>SVG Included with <object> tag</title>

<style>
.centre_image
{
text-align:center;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<table border="1" style="width:100%">
    <tr>
    <td class="centre_image">
        <object type="image/svg+xml" data="images/lawfirms.svg">   
          <img src="images/lawfirms.png" alt=""/>     
        </object>
    </td>
    <td class="centre_image">
        <object type="image/svg+xml" data="images/industry.svg">     
          <img src="images/industry.png" alt=""/>     
        </object>
    </td>
    <td class="centre_image">
        <object type="image/svg+xml" data="images/in-house.svg">     
          <img src="images/in-house.png" alt=""/>     
        </object>
    </td>
    </tr>
</table>

 </body>
</html>
```

Here is the result of Naresh Kumar's answer:
[image]

Comment: There is no `center` value for the float property also please set up a [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Try resetting your .css behavior for <table>, <tr>, <td>, <object> and <img>. It will help with browsers inconsistencies.

Comment: That doesn't look like tabular data...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As there is no `float:center` property, have you tried `text-align:center`?

```
.centre_image {
    text-align:center;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/ESWnh/)**

Comment: Thank you for the jsFiddle example, but the table still renders the same. I've put the full .html file as an EDIT to my question, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Thanks to all who answered! The problem was with my images themselves - as a novice user of Inkscape, I had left my .svg files as 600x400 in size - and as the image itself wasn't centred on the canvas, I mistakenly thought that it was being rendered incorrectly in the cell. Fixed the .svg files in Inkscape and then the `text-align:center` CSS attribute worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

try something like :

```
.centre_image{
    text-align:center;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
```

i hope that this will help you.

Comment: Thank you for your input Francois, unfortunately this makes no difference - see the EDIT to my question and response to j08691's answer.

Answer (score 0):

In HTML5 vAlign is deprecated. Here is a tips put all three images in side li tag. And in CSS assign a property display: inline block for the li tag.

Comment: Thanks for your input Naresh, please see the result in the edit I have made to my question.

Answer (score 0):

There were many ways to not make it right. Especially the 'float:center'.

I [fiddled an example](http://jsfiddle.net/ESWnh/1/) here
and another [fiddle with basic .css](http://jsfiddle.net/ESWnh/2/) reset here

Since you want to center horizontaly in a TD tag, you can simply align it ..

```
<td align="center">
```

But you will be noticed that 'align' property is 'deprecated' and you will be suggested to use CSS instead. For this, others already showed you the answer

```
.centre_image {
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

This CSS will work for as long has your element is not 'floated'

p.s. 'DEPRECATED' is not evil.

p.s. w3school has a [not so good reputation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=w3school) on StackOverflow.

Comment: Tell me, is '<table **border="1"**'> deprecated ?

Comment: Thank you for your input Milche, but text-align:center doesn't work for me. Please see my comment to j80691's answer and the edit to my question where I've listed the full HTML. I'm probably doing something really basic wrong :-)

Comment: No, according to http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_table_border.asp, the border attribute is not deprecated. Removing it seems to make no difference.

Comment: Thank you Milche, I think an issue may be that my .SVG files are a lot larger than I thought they were - 600x400 pixels. I am going to fix that and try again. I thought they were 270x270 but it seems not - I'm just learning to use Inkscape so need to revisit my files. Will post back with result.